# Is it legal to use windows 7 home premium as business?

Tags: windows-7, windows, license

Someone told me this was illegal, is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it isn't illegal, Home Premium is for the home user and focused around Entertainment, And business is for business and focuses on Security, Reliability, Remote Desktop, Etc.

If it's just a normal Home Premium licence, you can just use it at business as you please.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. There are some limitations on specific parts (use the software for commercial software hosting services; MPEG encoding) , but I couldn't see anything restricting the use for a general business use.

Comment: What? MPEG encoding?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: There is no windows 7 'Business'  'reliability' isn't specific to any version. For an actual comparison see: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/products/compare

Comment: I believe the only legal 'gotchas' around using windows in a business is related to discounted educational versions

Comment: @BloodPhilia cite your source

Comment: @Draemon lol, excuse me? Official reseller here... you might be a little nicer.

Comment: @BloodPhilia in what way was I unpleasant? Your answer is perfectly correct as far as I can tell, but as stated it's just an oppinion and would be greatly improved by supporting it with a source. Being a reseller doesn't make you right (they frequently misunderstand Microsoft licensing terms and often contradict each other in my experience). Had your answer said "I'm an official reseller" we would have known where the information / oppinion came from, had you pointed at a relevant part of the license text we would have known your source. As it was written it's just an unsupported assertion.

Answer (score 8):

The name is for branding purposes (and to indicate the features enabled/disabled on it). It has nothing to do with its licensed use.

For instance: As per the MCITP 70-680, the only difference between 7 ultimate and 7 enterprise is volume licensing (available in enterprise, not in ultimate)

Answer (score 4):

Not illegal, but for larger businesses (ie have a server and more than a handful of users) the benefits of using Active Directory become greater, and the Home editions simply can't be added to a domain, so for those situations it's a matter of practicality not legality.